# phonegap html 5 audio play stop working on iOS11

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, ios11, phonegap

My App streams audio from a shoutcast stream, but with iOS11 update play / pause button that fire Javascript for HTML 5 audio is not working any more

```
var audio = new Audio('http://radio.stream.net:1234/;stream/1');
audio.play();
```

I just update phonegap CLI and Xcode 
If i compile from Xcode on iPhone 7 simulator it doen't work

Comment: any update on this, did you figured it out ?

Comment: what we got from the shoutcast provider is a live transcoding to HLS

Comment: can you elaborate more, any workarounds?

Comment: I can't because is a transcoding option offered from the streaming service, i just call a different path

Answer (score 0):

The reason shoutcast server no longer works in the version of Safari bundled with iOS11 is because iOS11 no longer support HTTP/0.9, and the original ShoutCast server is very old and uses a custom protocol called "ICY", which is HTTP-like, but not standard compliant.

However, if you are the server administrator, there is a relatively easy workaround: install nginx as a reverse proxy in front of shoutcast server, and it will upgrade the HTTP version for you without any complaints.

The configuration you need for nginx looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 81;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        ngx.arg[1] = ngx.re.sub(ngx.arg[1], "^ICY ([0-9]+) ", "HTTP/1.0 $1 ")
    }
  }
}
```

This will map http://example.com:81 to your shoutcast server. You can then embed this link in the HTML5  tag, and iOS11 Safari will play it just fine.

In the example from the question, I assume you are the administrator of http://radio.steam.net and can run nginx on that server. In this case, your nginx config would look like

```
server {
  listen 81;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://radio.stream.net:1234;
    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        ngx.arg[1] = ngx.re.sub(ngx.arg[1], "^ICY ([0-9]+) ", "HTTP/1.0 $1 ")
    }
  }
}
```

and your audio script would look like

```
var audio = new Audio('http://radio.stream.net:81/;stream/1');
audio.play();
```